# Is it possible to use FB SDK custom events on Facebook Adverts

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the Cordova Facebook SDK plugin to log custom events, which I am able to track as expected in Facebook insights. I am now trying to track these same events (i.e. custom events) in Facebook Adverts as well. It seems possible to track certain predefined events, but it does not seem to be clear if there is a way to track custom events instead of the predefined ones.

Does anyone know if this is in fact possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not seem to be possible to use custom events, the solution as suggested to me by Facebook is to use one of the pre-defined events that is not used for anything else, and attribute that the event you are tracking.